# Using views Org Chart in Drupal

Tags: views, entities

I am trying to use Views org chart module in drupal.
I have created a node type contact using CCK module which stores in personal details of any person.
I have used relation module to  create relation between contacts like father - son relationship.

Now I wish to display the records in the hierarchical format.

For this i am trying to use Org chart module

[image]

Here is my setting for views.

I have added a relation isFatherof in relationship in views and in tile have checked in option is relationship

Below is my setting of org chart module

[image]

The view doesnt work but gives weird results